# Hide\Delete Smart Capture specific Element, based on Cloudpage parameter

Tags: ampscript, cloudpage, smart-capture

First of all, i'm not a developer but a good learner (thanks to comunities like this!).
And i know: smart capture forms are a great challenge (and a risky one).

This is my context: two different events have a slightly different subscription form, with some controls (input text and checkbox) required in form A but not in form B.
The flow is as usual:

1. Sent email with cloudpage link to smart capture form
2. On the cloudpage take parameters with requestParameter()
3. There's one parameter to request form A or form B

Now, my first attempts was to play with ampscript and "display: none" property to delete programmatically a smart capture block (`<div class="smartcapture-controls">`), wrapping this block with an external `<div>`.
But this doesn't work:

```
%%[var @msg, @mydisplay 
set @msg = RequestParameter("msg") 
 /*some logic to implement and then, for the form with controls to be deleted:*/ 

set @mydisplay = Concat('"', 'style=display: none','"') 
]%%
```

On the html code of specific smart capture control i've tried with **v()** and **treatAsContent()** but at no avail (control is always visible):

```
<div %%=treatascontent(@mydisplay)=%%>
  <div class="smartcapture-controls">
    <div class="sc-formfield-label">
      <label for="LastName">LastName</label>
    </div>
    <div class="sc-formfield-input">
      <input type="text" id="LastName" name="LastName" data-field-type="Text">
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

and

```
<div %%=v(@mydisplay)=%%>
  <div class="smartcapture-controls">
    <div class="sc-formfield-label">
      <label for="LastName">LastName</label>
    </div>
    <div class="sc-formfield-input">
      <input type="text" id="LastName" name="LastName" data-field-type="Text">
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Interesting, with **treatAsContent()** the html source page has the div with the desired setting, although the evidence to have the control not stripped out:

```
-- from source code page
<div "style=display: none">
  <div class="smartcapture-controls">
    <div class="sc-formfield-label">
      <label for="LastName">LastName</label>
    </div>
<div class="sc-formfield-input">
  <input type="text" id="LastName" name="LastName" data-field-type="Text">
</div>
```

So far my attempts.

Maybe a different aproach may be setting a client side javascript variable from ampscript and then hide element with DOM?
Or is this not a best practice at all? (so i have to switch to the simple 2-cloudpage and 2-form instead?)

Thanks in advance and best regards

Paolo